# More binomial coefficients and FORTRAN 95

Tags: fortran, memoization

I'm trying to write a function/subroutine which calculates binomial coefficients for large n and k (n choose k).  A couple days ago I posted a subroutine which worked okay but with very slight decimal error.  The problem seemed to be due to dividing very large numbers.  Anyway, I thought it might be better to try a recursive algorithm as addition might not have this problem.  Additionally, given the large numbers involved memorization would be necessary.  Here is a function I wrote in the statistical language R, which seems to work pretty well,

```
 options("scipen"=100)
 mm <- matrix(0,100,100)
 combo <- function (n,k) {
       if (k==1) {
       return(n)
       }
       if (k==n) {
       return(1)
       }
       if (mm[n,k] != 0) {
       return(mm[n,k])
       }
       if (k!=1 & n!=k) {
       ans <<- combo(n-1,k) + combo(n-1,k-1)
       mm[n,k] <<- ans
       return(combo(n-1,k) + combo(n-1,k-1))
       }
 }
 combo(40,20)
```

I need to be able to do the same thing in FORTRAN 95.  Here is the recursive code without memorization, which works fine

```
 program fctrecur
 implicit none
 integer (kind=8) i,j,combo

 print*,"What is n?"
 read*,i

 print*,"What is k?"
 read*,j

 print*,combo(i,j)
 end  

 recursive function combo(n,k) result(cmb)
 implicit none
 integer (kind=8) n,k,cmb
 if (k .EQ. n) then
    cmb = 1
 endif
 if (k .EQ. 1) then
    cmb = n
 endif
 if ((k .NE. 1) .AND. (k .NE. n)) then
    cmb = combo(n-1,k-1) + combo(n-1,k)
 endif      
 end function
```

My question is...can the above FORTRAN program be modified to incorporate memorization?  I have tried to mimic the R function but nothing seems to work.  Thanks, Jerry

The module suggestion from Vladimir F works very well...but I can't get it to work as an internal function.  Here's the code

```
 program fctrecur
 implicit none
 integer, parameter :: iknd = selected_int_kind(18)
 integer(kind=iknd) :: mm(100,100)
 integer (kind=iknd) i,j,combo

 print*,"What is n?"
 read*,i

 print*,"What is k?"
 read*,j

 print*,combo(i,j)
 end

 recursive function combo(n,k) result(cmb)
 integer, parameter :: iknd = selected_int_kind(18)
 integer(kind=iknd) :: cmb
 integer(kind=iknd), intent(in) :: n,k

if (k == n) then
    cmb = 1
else if (k == 1) then
    cmb = n
else if (mm(n,k) /=0)  then
        print*,"hello"
    cmb = mm(n,k)
else if ((k /= 1) .and. (k /= n)) then
    cmb = combo(n-1,k-1) + combo(n-1,k)
    mm(n,k) = cmb
end if      

 end function
```

which gives the following error
"The left hand side of an assignment statement must be a variable or a function result" for the line
mm(n,k) = cmb.  Even if I declare the array mm within the function it doesn't work (it works, but ignores the memoization, "mm(n,k)=cmb"

I figured it out...

```
 program fctrecur
 implicit none
 integer i,j,mm(50,50)

 print*,"What is n?"
 read*,i

 print*,"What is k?"
 read*,j

 print*,combo(i,j)

 contains
 recursive function combo(n,k) result(cmb)
 implicit none
 integer cmb
 integer, intent(in) :: n,k

 if (k == n) then
    cmb = 1
 else if (k == 1) then
    cmb = n
 else if (mm(n,k) /=0)  then
        print*,"hello"
    cmb = mm(n,k)
 else if ((k /= 1) .and. (k /= n)) then
    cmb = combo(n-1,k-1) + combo(n-1,k)
    mm(n,k) = cmb
 end if      

 end function
 end program
```

I just used regular INTEGER for now...will adjust to allow much larger n and k.

Here is the final code that works well for quite large n and k

main program

```
 program fctrecur
 use binom
 implicit none
 integer i,j

 print *, "What is n?"
 read *, i

 allocate(mm(i,i))
 mm = 0.D0

 print *, "What is k?"
 read *, j

 print *,combo(i,j)

 end
```

module

```
 module binom
 implicit none

 integer, parameter :: iknd = selected_real_kind(31)
 real(iknd), allocatable ::  mm(:,:)

 contains

 recursive function combo(n,k) result(cmb)
 real (kind=iknd) :: cmb
 integer, intent(in) :: n,k
    if (k == n) then
    cmb = real(1,16)
 else if (k == 1) then
    cmb = real(n,16)
 else if (mm(n,k) /=0)  then
    cmb = mm(n,k)
 else if ((k /= 1) .and. (k /= n)) then
    cmb = combo(n-1,k-1) + combo(n-1,k)
    mm(n,k) = cmb
 end if      
 end function

 end module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pretty serious error in your R code. You are computing everything twice (although the memoization helps here)!
You should use:

```
   ans <<- combo(n-1,k) + combo(n-1,k-1)
   mm[n,k] <<- ans
   return(ans)
```

This how it looks in Fortran. It is a completely straightforward translation.

```
module binom
  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: iknd = selected_int_kind(36)
  ! 36 is necessary for very large n and k, integer(kind=8) wasn't enough!

  integer(iknd) :: mm(100,100)

contains

  recursive function combo(n,k) result(cmb)
    integer(kind=iknd) :: cmb
    integer(kind=iknd), intent(in) :: n,k

    if (k == n) then
        cmb = 1
    else if (k == 1) then
        cmb = n
    else if (mm(n,k) /=0)  then
        cmb = mm(n,k)
    else if ((k /= 1) .and. (k /= n)) then
        cmb = combo(n-1,k-1) + combo(n-1,k)
        mm(n,k) = cmb
    end if      
  end function

end module

program fctrecur
  use binom

  implicit none

  integer(kind=iknd) i,j

  print *, "What is n?"
  read *, i

  print *, "What is k?"
  read *, j

  print *,combo(i,j)
  print *,combo(i,j)

end
```

Notice the function is in a module, you could also define it internal to the program and move the array `mm` to the main program. External functions are remnants of the past and are not preferred for new code. Internal and module procedures receive an "explicit interface" which helps to find errors and enables many advanced passing mechanisms.

In the final code you want the array allocatable and you want to make sure you do not exceed the bounds, but you do not do that in R either, so I left out that for you.

Notice the `selected_int_kind` to define the kind in a  portable way, `kind=8` is not portable and is strongly discouraged. In your case `kind=8` was actually too low to allow large `n` close to 100.

You can use the much more readable operators `==` and `/=`.

Notice that the structure of the conditionals should be done using `else if` because you do not have any immediate `return` statements in the individual branches.

Generally, I would recommend you to read some good modern Fortran tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for all the information...appreciated.  Correct about the R code...doing the same thing twice...surprised it doesn't affect speed in a noticeable way.  Unfortunately the FORTRAN memoization still does not work.  It seems the problem is that the line mm(n,k) = cmb in the last conditional is never invoked (perhaps the function call in the previous line is the problem, although this doesn't happen in R).  You can verify this by putting a simple print statement (print*,"3rd condition") in the conditional for the if/then line testing m(n,k) \= 0...nothing is ever printed out

Comment: UPDATE: your suggestion worked when I used the module instead of making an separate function within the program...thanks a lot!

Comment: An internal function works too, look into the edit history of my post.

Comment: I saw that...but couldn't get it working (see code above from edit of original post).  Can you suggest a FORTRAN 95 tutorial?

Comment: Definitely read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_95_language_features . There are many tutorials at http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Tutorials , this one is from a very respected author http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/nmm1/Fortran/index.html